# SSH into Kubernetes cluster running on Amazon

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, kubernetes

Created a 2 node Kubernetes cluster as:

```
KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=aws NUM_NODES=2 kube-up.sh
```

This shows the output as:

```
Found 2 node(s).
NAME                                         STATUS    AGE
ip-172-20-0-226.us-west-2.compute.internal   Ready     57s
ip-172-20-0-227.us-west-2.compute.internal   Ready     55s
Validate output:
NAME                 STATUS    MESSAGE              ERROR
controller-manager   Healthy   ok                   
scheduler            Healthy   ok                   
etcd-0               Healthy   {"health": "true"}   
etcd-1               Healthy   {"health": "true"}   
Cluster validation succeeded
Done, listing cluster services:

Kubernetes master is running at https://52.33.9.1
Elasticsearch is running at https://52.33.9.1/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/elasticsearch-logging
Heapster is running at https://52.33.9.1/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster
Kibana is running at https://52.33.9.1/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kibana-logging
KubeDNS is running at https://52.33.9.1/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns
kubernetes-dashboard is running at https://52.33.9.1/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard
Grafana is running at https://52.33.9.1/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-grafana
InfluxDB is running at https://52.33.9.1/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-influxdb
```

I can see the instances in EC2 console. How do I ssh into the master node?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the exact command that worked for me:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/kube_aws_rsa admin@<masterip>
```

`kube_aws_rsa` is the default key generated, otherwise controlled with `AWS_SSH_KEY` environment variable. For AWS, it is specified in the file `cluster/aws/config-default.sh`.

More details about the cluster can be found using `kubectl.sh config view`.

Comment: Hi Arun, i tried this command but it ask for passphrase. where as i have not created passphrase at all while creating pribate key.

Comment: @ShruthiBhaskar it's possible that your user is not `admin`.  Try something like `root`

Answer (score 0):

"Creates an AWS SSH key named kubernetes-. Fingerprint here is the OpenSSH key fingerprint, so that multiple users can run the script with different keys and their keys will not collide (with near-certainty). It will use an existing key if one is found at AWS_SSH_KEY, otherwise it will create one there. (With the default Ubuntu images, if you have to SSH in: the user is ubuntu and that user can sudo"

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/design/aws_under_the_hood.md

You should see the ssh key-fingerprint locally in ssh config or set the ENV and recreate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are throwing up your cluster on AWS with kops, and use CoreOS as your image, then the login name would be "core".